# Implementing DatePicker / DatePickerFlyout on TextBox Tapped

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-10

I am working on Windows 10 Universal app and I am confused on how to implement DatePicker on textbox tap. As soon I click on Textbox I want datepicker to showup.
I have tried Tapped and OnFocus event and call datepicker using C# but that didn't help.
Is their any other way to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Background

The CalendarDatePicker in UWP in an actual UI Control. Which means it got it's own event, UI and ways to be used.

Which means that if I add a simple CalendarDatePicker to my UI like this:

```
        var picker = new CalendarDatePicker();
        mainGrid.Children.Add(picker);
```

I would produce a control like this:

[image: Image showing a closed CalendarDatePicker]

And if I press the "select a date" button:

[image: Image showing a open CalendarDatePicker calendar view]

My recommendation is to use that instead, since they've already solved a lot of problems and created everything for you. BUT, if you really want to use your own TextBox, nothing is stopping you from doing that. It's just a bit more cumbersome.

### Solving initial problem

This is one option to use to make a Calendar view show up when you focus a TextBox:

```
    private void CalendarDatePicker_DateChanged(CalendarDatePicker sender, CalendarDatePickerDateChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        calendar.IsCalendarOpen = false;
        textBox.Text = args.NewDate?.DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }

    private void textBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calendar.IsCalendarOpen = true;
    }
```

And the corresponding XAML:

```
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" PlaceholderText="Press me!" Tapped="Btn_Tapped" GotFocus="textBox_GotFocus" Height="100" />
    <CalendarDatePicker x:Name="calendar" Width="0" Height="0" DateChanged="CalendarDatePicker_DateChanged" />
```

PS. The trick is to set the CalendarDatePicker Height and Width to zero, that makes the actual button invisible, but still lets the Calendar flyout be visible when setting `IsCalendarOpen = true`

I hope that helps. Would love to hear feedback or critique about the answer :)

Have a good day!